# Socket being closed by try with resources

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, try-with-resources

I'm trying to write some simple socket code that has the following basic form -

```
try(BufferedReader request = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()))){
//Do some work...
}
//BufferedReader gets closed, but also makes the socket close
...
...
response.write(blah);//Causes exception because socket is closed
```

My problem is that the socket is being closed, but I don't think it should be. The try-with-resources creates a BufferedReader and then auto-closes it when I leave the try block, but for some reason it also closes the entire socket! So when I get to my response code later on that uses the same socket I get an exception. Is there any way to fix this? Or do I just have to not use a try-with-resources (which would be less than ideal)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BufferedReader.close() closes the backing stream.

The way to work around is a "wrapping" stream that doesn't propagate the close()

Comment: Do you happen to know what streams dont propagate the close()?

Comment: None in the java runtime. You'd need to write your own

Comment: "BufferedReader.close() closes the backing stream" ... and closing either the input or the output stream of a socket closes the other stream and the socket itself.

Answer (score 1):

The code :

```
new BufferedReader(
   new InputStreamReader(
      sock.getInputStream()))
```

wrap the socket stream into a reader wrapped into a BufferedReader, but it's the one and the only stream.